# Pyroute2 import error - import AF_BRIDGE

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-3.5, openbsd

whenever I'm trying to run the sample script of pyroute2 module :

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
ip = IPRoute()
print([x.get_attr('IFLA_IFNAME') for x in ip.get_links()])
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 2, in <module>
    ip = IPRoute()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyroute2\__init__.py", line 122, in __new_
_
    cls.register(cls.registry['class'])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyroute2\__init__.py", line 102, in __geti
tem__
    [name], 0)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyroute2\iproute.py", line 175, in <module
>
    from socket import AF_BRIDGE
ImportError: cannot import name 'AF_BRIDGE'
```

The main platform I'm trying to use pyroute2 is OpenBSD but the problem remains for other platforms like windows .

I tested this around both python3.5 and python2.7 in addition to python3.4.

Just don't know how to solve this problem.
any idea ?

thanks

Comment: As main developer stated at github, it's for linux and is not working on other platforms .

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, from official [pyroute2 git repository](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2):

> Pyroute2 is a pure Python netlink and Linux network configuration library. It requires only Python stdlib, no 3rd party libraries. Later it can change, but the deps tree will remain as simple, as it is possible.

So, OpenBSD and Windows are not Linux systems. OpenBSD does not support `AF_BRIDGE` and is only supported on [Linux kernel](https://grok.dragonflybsd.org/search?q=AF_BRIDGE&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&type=&project=linux&project=openbsd). If you want to execute your script, you need to:

- [Create an interface](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2/blob/master/pyroute2/iproute.py) for OpenBSD in pyroute2, try to open a ticket first.
- Port `AF_BRIDGE` on OpenBSD (I don't think this will be accepted by the community).
- Find another alternative to do what you want.

About alternative, if you only need to check your route table, you can find good alternative with:

- [Salt](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.network.html) (supported on Linux, Windows and *BSD)
- [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#routing) (oriented security)
- [Rex](https://www.rexify.org/docs/api/1.3/rex/commands/network.pm.html) (compatible with Linux and OpenBSD but in Perl)

Comment: Pyroute2 has partial support (getters only, no setters) for BSD. See https://docs.pyroute2.org/iproute.html#module-pyroute2.iproute.bsd